# Iterate through Date for the last 7 days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to build a array of objects to show data on a graph which shows the data for the last 7 days. At times certain of the 7 days record will be absent in the database and hence i need to show the record and mark the value as 0 to have 7 objects in the array.

Right now i have

```
[
  {
    "date": "2016-05-14",
    "amount": 6000
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-05-12",
    "amount": 12000
  }
]
```

What i want is

```
[
    {
        "date": "2016-05-14",
        "amount": 6000
    },
    {
        "date": "2016-05-13",
        "amount": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2016-05-12",
        "amount": 12000
    },
    {
        "date": "2016-05-11",
        "amount": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2016-05-10",
        "amount": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2016-05-09",
        "amount": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2016-05-09",
        "amount": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you tell us, is date a field in your Table?

Comment: @PraveshKhatri `paid_on` yes thats the field so basically since there are records for those dates the data is being fetched. for the days its not i need to set the default value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ts = JSON.parse '[
{
  "date": "2016-05-14",
  "amount": 6000
},
{
  "date": "2016-05-12",
  "amount": 12000
}]' # support ruby < 2.2

((Date.today-6..Date.today).map do |d|
  [d.iso8601, {'amount' => 0, 'date' => d.iso8601 }]
end.to_h.merge ts.group_by { |e| e['date'] }).values.flatten
```

Here we start with building a hash of requested days mapped to zero values, then merge it against a hash of existing values. The latter takes precedence:

```
[Date.today].map do |d|
  [d.iso8601, {'amount' => 0, 'date' => d.iso8601 }]
end.to_h
#⇒ { '2016-05-16' => {'amount' => 0, 'date' => '2016-05-16' } }
```

(in the real hash there are seven items.)

[`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) produces the same structure:

```
[ {'amount' => 42, 'date' => Date.today } ].group_by { |e| e['date'] }
#⇒ { '2016-05-16' => [{'amount' => 42, 'date' => '2016-05-16' }] }
```

As a last step, we merge the latter into the former and get rid of date keys by taking `values` of a result and flattening it.

---

Using `Hash#default_proc`:

```
hsh = Hash.new do |h, k|
  ts.detect do |e|
    e['date'] == k.iso8601
  end || { 'amount' => 0, 'date' => k.iso8601 }
end
(Date.today-6..Date.today).map { |d| hsh[d] }
```

Comment: @HarshaMV Dropped a bit of explanation.

Comment: thank you. I am trying to reproduce the code with mine. The out i showed you was a JSON adapted. but in my code i seem to have activerecord. so its creating duplicate records

Comment: Please paste what the output of `initial_array.group_by { |e| e['date'] }` is.

Comment: I am getting the following output http://pastebin.com/bQHpAUft

will check that and share it as well one sec

Comment: The Output is this http://pastebin.com/eD8wxrbs for `initial_array.group_by { |e| e['date'] }`

Comment: What you are posting is the result of call to `to_json` (since it is a result of render.) It looks like your initial hash has if fact _symbols_ as keys, not strings. Please try to change: `[d.iso8601, ...]` ⇒ `[d.iso8601.to_sym, ...]` in the second line. Or maybe a change `end.to_h.merge` ⇒ `end.to_h.with_indifferent_access.merge` should help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112033/discussion-between-harsha-m-v-and-mudasobwa).

Answer (score 2):

A functional approach via map reduce is probably simplest and most efficient:

```
timeseries = [
  {
    "date":   "2016-05-14",
    "amount": 6000
  },
  {
    "date":   "2016-05-12",
    "amount": 12000
  }
]

last_7_days     = 6.days.ago.to_date..Date.today

# Transform array of hashes into a single hash with each key as a Date object.
#  Eg. { "2016-05-12" => 12000, "2016-05-14" => 6000 }
counts_each_day = timeseries.reduce(Hash.new(0)) do |acc, item|
  acc.merge(Date.parse(item[:date]) => item[:amount])
end

# Merge the results with an empty count, if it doesn't exist in our transformed hash.
filled_timeseries = last_7_days.map do |day|
  { date: day.to_s, amount: counts_each_day[day] }
end
```

**Result**

```
[
  { :date => "2016-05-10", :amount => 0 },
  { :date => "2016-05-11", :amount => 0 },
  { :date => "2016-05-12", :amount => 12000 },
  { :date => "2016-05-13", :amount => 0 },
  { :date => "2016-05-14", :amount => 6000 },
  { :date => "2016-05-15", :amount => 0 },
  { :date => "2016-05-16", :amount => 0 }
]
```

Comment: `no implicit conversion of Date into String` am getting the following error

Comment: `acc.merge(Date.parse(item[:date]) => item[:amount])` that line

Comment: Are you pasting the code as-is? It works for me on Rails 4.2.5 and Ruby 2.2.4

Comment: yes. copy pasted. i am also on `4.2.5.2` and `2.2.4`

Comment: `item[:date]` should be a string, not a date object. Are the keys of your date array strings and not Ruby date objects?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112020/discussion-between-harsha-m-v-and-anthony-e).

Comment: "undefined method `days' for 6:Integer." I am getting this error

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

```
data = [
{
  "date": "2016-05-14",
  "amount": 6000
},
{
  "date": "2016-05-12",
  "amount": 12000
}] # Given data
dates = data.map do |datum| datum[:date] end # Extract dates from data.
today = Date.today # Get today.
dates_list = 7.times.map do |index| (today + index).strftime("%F") end # Get 7days from today.
dates_list.each do |date|
  next if dates.include? date # if data already includes the date, such as "2016-05-14", pass.
  data << {"date": date, "amount": 0} # if data does not include the date, append it with amount 0.
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get the right answer:

```
require 'date'
require 'pp'

data = [
  {
    "date": "2016-05-14",
    "amount": 6000
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-05-12",
    "amount": 12000
  }
]

pp data

today = DateTime.now

7.times do |day|
  current_day = (DateTime.now - day).strftime("%F")
  next if data.find_index {|hash| hash[:date] == current_day }
  data.push({ "date": current_day, "amount": 0 })
end

pp data
```

This will produce the following output:

```
[{:date=>"2016-05-14", :amount=>6000},
 {:date=>"2016-05-12", :amount=>12000},
 {:date=>"2016-05-15", :amount=>0},
 {:date=>"2016-05-13", :amount=>0},
 {:date=>"2016-05-11", :amount=>0},
 {:date=>"2016-05-10", :amount=>0},
 {:date=>"2016-05-09", :amount=>0}]
```

If you want the array sorted by date, you can use this:

```
data.sort {|a,b| a[:date] <=> b[:date] }.reverse
```

This will produce this output:

```
[{:date=>"2016-05-15", :amount=>0},
 {:date=>"2016-05-14", :amount=>6000},
 {:date=>"2016-05-13", :amount=>0},
 {:date=>"2016-05-12", :amount=>12000},
 {:date=>"2016-05-11", :amount=>0},
 {:date=>"2016-05-10", :amount=>0},
 {:date=>"2016-05-09", :amount=>0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach that I think is fairly clear, and gets the start date from the data rather than Date.today.  It assumes that there are no invalid dates in the input, and that the input is not empty.

Note that by specifying `"string":...` something you are saying the same thing as `string:...` but in a much more confusing way.  I guess this is from JSON data, but it should be parsed into a Ruby array of hashes.  I've changed this in my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'date'


def to_date(string)
  Date.strptime(string, '%Y-%m-%d')
end


# Transform the input to a hash whose keys are date objects
# and whose values are the original input records
def transform_input_to_hash(input_records)
  input_records.each_with_object({}) do |record, hsh|
    key = to_date(record[:date])
    hsh[key] = record
  end
end


def fill_in_missing_dates(input_records)
  input_record_hash = transform_input_to_hash(input_records)

  start_date = input_record_hash.keys.first
  output_dates = ((start_date - 6)..start_date).to_a.reverse

  output_dates.each_with_object([]) do |date, array|
    array << if input_record_hash.keys.include?(date)
      input_record_hash[date]
    else
      { date: date, amount: 0 }
    end
  end
end



INPUT_RECORDS = [
  {
    date: "2016-05-14",
    amount: 6000
  },
  {
    date: "2016-05-12",
    amount: 12000
  }
]



output_array = fill_in_missing_dates(INPUT_RECORDS)
puts output_array
```

By the way, this works in Ruby without Rails.  Also, the code is posted at https://gist.github.com/keithrbennett/fd876aac938f1e5d6222896dbd30e8f2.